# JSPM mapping files between different domains

Tags: javascript, jspm

Suppose this silly situation where our web client fetches the project from its server "mainserver.app.com". And it has app.js that requires app2.js.

Instead of the domain "mainserver.app.com", we wanna fetch the same project from "api.app.com".

Also, the project from "api.app.com" is hashed.
This is possible using the `map` configuration of [JSPM](http://www.jspm.io):

```
{
  "../app.js":"api.app.com/app-hash.js"
}
```

The problem comes as the "api.app.com/app-hash.js" requires "./app2.js" (which is now hashed) and this does not work :

```
{
  "../app2.js":"api.app.com/app2-hash.js"
}
```

neither this

```
{
  "api.app.com/app2.js":"api.app.com/app2-hash.js"
}
```

Any idea is appreciated.